# Index of norm $ 1 $ subgroup in a cyclic extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, galois-theory, eigenvalues, galois-groups

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be a cyclic galois extension of degree $  2n $ and $\sigma $ be a generator of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb Q)$. Let $ U $ be the collection of all norm $ 1 $ elements of $L^\times$. Then $ U $ is a subgroup of $ L^{\times} $ = the set of all non zero elements in $L$.
Now what is the index of the subgroup $ U $ of $ L^{\times} $?

Note: By Hilbert's theorem 90 we have $ U =\{\sigma(a)/a : a\in L^{\times}\} $.  So one can consider the map $  \phi : L^{\times} \rightarrow L^{\times} $ by $ \phi(a) = \sigma(a)/a $. Then $ L^{\times}/ \mathbb{Q}^\times \cong U $.

Comment: Actually $U = \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$.  In fact, $L^\times/U$ is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname N_{L/\mathbb Q})$, not, as far as I can see, to $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$.  Or did you mean something else? \\ Also, this index will always be infinite in your setting, so are you sure that's what you mean to ask about?

Comment: Yes @Lspice you are right, I have edited my question.

Comment: Yes @Lspice if we consider norm map then image of this map will be required  quotient  group. But does  the map subjective?

Comment: I'm not sure what map you [mean](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405828/index-of-norm-1-subgroup-in-a-cyclic-extension#comment1040496_405828).  The norm map $L^\times/U \to \operatorname{Im}(\operatorname N_{L/\mathbb Q})$ is definitely surjective, by the definition of the image, and even an isomorphism; and the image includes $(\mathbb Q^\times)^{2n}$, hence is infinite.  I am not claiming that $L^\times/U \to \mathbb Q^\times$ is surjective, and we do not need it to be for my claim.

Comment: Well, for cyclic extensions with roots of unity in the basefield, this is Kummer theory. But, more generally, isn't this verging on classfield theory? Already for abelian extensions of local fields, the "norm residue map/theorem" is a serious thing: for unramified extensions it's relatively easy to understand, but not in general. The analogue for global fields (e.g., number fields) is classfield theory! Not an easy or obvious thing. Am I maybe misunderstanding something? (Not all sub-questions of difficult questions are difficult... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett, obviously you have understood this question better than I have.  Your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405828/index-of-norm-1-subgroup-in-a-cyclic-extension#comment1040531_405828) seems to be about the quotient $\mathbb Q^\times/\operatorname N_{L/\mathbb Q}(L^\times)$, right?  But the question seems to be about $L^\times/\ker \operatorname N_{L/\mathbb Q}$—and not even about its structure, but its cardinality, which is infinite, right?  What am I missing?

Comment: @LSpice, dunno. My reaction was/is just a charades-sort-of-thing "sounds like" [tugs ear]. There are certainly versions of such a question that have no sensible answers, and some that have trivial... and more interesting ones in-between. Possibly the original asker can refine the question...

Comment: @LSpice, I guess some version of the question is just Hilbert's Thm 90 for cyclic extensions... and whether it extends... which it does not, etc. Dunno.

Comment: I voted to close, because the index of $U$ in $L^\times$ is infinite ($\omega$) for obvious reasons (as LSpice explained). If the OP meant to ask something else, he should ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @Lspice I want to to know the image of $ N(L/\mathbb {Q})$ I.e which points  of $ \mathbb{Q}^{\times)$ are in the image set.

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405828/index-of-norm-1-subgroup-in-a-cyclic-extension#comment1040582_405828) is a different question.  As [@paulgarrett](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405828/index-of-norm-1-subgroup-in-a-cyclic-extension#comment1040546_405828) and [@‍GHfromMO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405828/index-of-norm-1-subgroup-in-a-cyclic-extension#comment1040556_405828) say, you should clarify what you are asking, possibly in a new question.  (For example, what kind of characterisation of the image would be acceptable?  Can it use global class-field theory?)